# Extract Admin OG members from basic page with views

Tags: views, blocks, organic-groups, users

I have added a group reference field to basic pages. That is every book page belongs to an OG group. When displaying a basic page, I want to display the list of admin members of the OG group in a block.

So, I have a view in a block with the following :

### In contextual filters

Content: Nid

### In Relationships

OG membership: OG membership from Node
(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group Node from OG membership
(Group node from OG membership) OG membership: OG membership from Node group
(OG membership from node group) OG membership: User from OG membership

### In fields

(user from OG membership) User: Name (User name)

This view display all the users of the group associated to the current basic page.
Now, how can I filter theses users to only keep the ones which have an "administer member" role ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is it mean "empty roles"?

Comment: I have changed the description to make it clearer. I removed the empty roles description as it is not important. Empty roles means when you print it, it is null.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution by doing the following

### In Relationships

OG membership: OG membership from Node
(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group Node from OG membership
(Group node from OG membership) OG membership: OG membership from Node group
(OG membership from node group) OG membership: User from OG membership
**(OG membership from node group) OG membership: OG Roles from membership**

### In filters

(OG Roles from OG membership) OG user roles: Role Name (= administer member)

The idea was to select the roles from the OG membership of the Group.

Answer (score 1):

Create new block (showing users) with these settings:

**Fields:**

User: Name

**Filter criteria:**

User: Roles (= administer member)

**Relationships:**

User: Content authored

**contextual filters:**

(nodes) Content: [your book reference field]

*provide default value -> Content ID from URL*

**Other:**

Query settings -> tick: `Distinct`, `Pure distinct`.

Comment: I don't think this will work since you are not using any OG information. But thanks.

Comment: Please try, it's only two minutes of work. Please comment results.

Comment: I can try but the problem is that I need to filter on OG roles. For example, I have a role called "singer". I cannot do that with this solution. I said "administer member" in my problem just for example.

Comment: not sure, but maybe you're right. Your problem has been solved, so nevermind.